# Find closest value in the graph coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have `List<Summary>` objects in Java where each `Summary` object contains 2 fields - quantity and days
This data is plotted onto a graph where x-axis is days and y-axis is quantity
My reference points on the graph and all further calculations are based on y0 and y1
Lets assume my data set is as following

```
Y           X
100 (y0)    0
90  (y1)    1
80          2
75          5    
73          7
48          9
60          10
45          12
```

2 simple rules - 
1 - choose closest value
2 - if exactly in between choose higher value

Lets say I want to find out X for 50% of Y1 = (50 * 90 ) / 100 = 45 which yield me 8 as days

Likewise, lets say I want to find out X for 80% of Y1 = (80 * 90 ) / 100 = 72. Since we don't have an exact match on the Y axis we chose the close which is 73 so this yields me 7 days (here rule 1 is applied)

Likewise, lets say I want to find out X for 60% of Y1 = (60 * 90 ) / 100 = 54. Since we don't have an exact match on the Y axis and because 54 is exactly in the middle of 48 and 60, this yields me 10 (rule 2 is applied)

What is the best way to achieve this in java? Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the lowest [residual sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares). This will fit a line to a series of points that are more or less in a line.

I would approach this problem with these steps.

1. Understand what the regression is doing. It's coming up with a best fit for that famous equation for a line, `y = mx + b`. The x is your day and the y is your quantity. m is the slope of the line (yours is negative, actually -4.124) and b is the intercept (yours is close to 100, actually 95.086).
2. Write the linear regression in Java. There are lots of these online, and you can search for it, but you will be a better person if you write it from scratch.
3. Using the output from step 2, do a little rearranging and find x in terms of y.
4. Put a y into the equation from step 3 (your first example: 45) and you'll come up with days. (I got 12.14, not your 8. Note that the last point is {12,45}.).
5. Round to the nearest day you have in your list.